# How to get whole row value if radio button on one cell is selected in php

Tags: php, html, database

I have a table in which data is coming from database. first 2 column's data is from another database query and others columns from anther query. The table is in following link:
[table pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYHLP.png)

Now what I wanted to do is, whenever any radio button in a cell is selected, then I get the value of first two columns of the same row in php and then send it to another page. 
The code is:

```
<?php
      $trainName;
      $trainNo="";
      $depart_time="";
      $train_name="";
      $class_id="";
      $full_berth="";
      $full_seat="";
      $seat="";
      $berth="";
      $con = $a->operation();
      if(($st_No2-$st_No)<1){
          $sql = "select t.train_no, t.train_name, TIME_FORMAT(tt.depart_time, '%H:%i:%s') As depart_time from trains t, train_timings tt where t.train_No = tt.train_No and tt.st_Code = '" .$_SESSION['from']. "' and t.train_No like '%DN'";
          $r = mysql_query($sql);



          echo "<tr >
      <col width='100' >
      <col width='80' >";

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
      $trainNo = $row["train_no"];
      $trainName = $row["train_name"];
        $sql4="select seat, berth, class_id from seat where train_no='$trainNo' and date='" .$_SESSION['dep_date']. "'"; 
         $r4= mysql_query($sql4);
         while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($r4)){
             $seat=$row4['seat'];
         $berth=$row4['berth'];}

           if($seat>0 and $berth>0){
             echo "<td>".$row["train_name"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["depart_time"]."</td>";
         //$trainNo = $row["train_no"];
         $depart_time= $row["depart_time"];
         $train_name= $row["train_name"];

            $query = "select c.class_id, f.full_berth, f.full_seat from class c inner join fare f on c.class_id = f.class_id where t_from='" .$_SESSION['from']. "' and t_to='" .$_SESSION['to']. "' and f.train_no='$trainNo'";
         $r1 = mysql_query($query);

         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r1)){
            $class_id= $row["class_id"];
            $full_berth= $row["full_berth"];
            $full_seat= $row["full_seat"];

            echo $row["class_id"];

            //echo "<td>".$class_id.$full_berth."</td>"."<td>".$class_id.$full_seat."</td>";

            echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='class1' value='$trainNo'><input type='hidden' id='class1' value='$class_id'><input type='radio' name='f1' value='$full_berth' onclick='classid()'><p>".$row["full_berth"]."&nbspPKR</p></td>"."<td><input type='hidden' id='class2' value=".$row["class_id"]."><input type='hidden' id='class2' value='$class_id'><input type='radio' name='f1' value='$full_seat' onclick='classid2()'><p>".$row["full_seat"]."&nbspPKR</p></td>";
            $class_id = "";
            //if(isset('f1')){
                //echo "$row['class_id']";
            //}


            //echo "<td><input type='radio' name='f1' value='$row['full_berth']'".$row["class_id"].$row["full_berth"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["class_id"].$row["full_seat"]."</td>";
            }  
           }
           echo "</tr>";
           }
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and what problems you've run into?

Comment: actually the table pic that  i have attached, in table whole data is populated from database and the table is automatically generated, now the problem is that data is from two different queries, I dont know how to refer whole row from one cell

Comment: How are you naming your radio buttons? I am not entirely sure but in this case the trick is to name the radio buttons so that you are getting the information that you need. It would be helpful if you could post your HTML/PHP code.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I have added my code is it helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, meaning that it interacts with the server only, and not the browser. Client-side languages, such as JavaScript, can react to client-side events like clicks.

Therefore, to do this, you would require JavaScript. I'll use jQuery to help make my examples simpler.

If you have a simple table with multiple rows with radio buttons, then you can simply create JavaScript events to send data to a PHP script.

```js
$("input:radio").change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var col1 = $(this).parent().parent().children("td:first");
    var col2 = col1.next();
    alert(col1.text() + " " + col2.text());
    /*  // send to php using AJAX
    $.ajax({
      url: "#",
      data: {col1: col1, col2: col2},
      method: "post"
    });
    */
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>Row1Col1</td><td>Row1Col2</td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row2Col1</td><td>Row2Col2</td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Mudassir I'm glad I helped!

Comment: one more thing to ask is, I wanted to store col1 and col2 variables in $_SESSION in php,  so that I can use it on more pages. Can you please help me in it? @Jonathan